# web application as desktop application

Tags: javascript, c#, web, node-webkit

I have a web application in c# .net, and have a problem that every user using other browser, and some of the users are big organizations and they have really old browsers like old IE.
When they logging in from this browser some of  the features cant work.

I need something to wrap the web application when user using it in the pc, something that will act like a browser but with out the ability to change address or click right click or other things like it and will be the same for all the users.

I tried to use Node-Webkit, and i did it like here:
[Use node-webkit for web app](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-html5-desktop-apps-with-node-webkit--net-36296)

The problem is that the user can see the package.json file and see the address of the site and can even change it.
The json file:

```
{
"name": "example-app",
"main": "http://www.XXXX.com",
"window": {
    "toolbar": false
}
```

}

There is some way to hide the config file or to package it in some way? or to use other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**CefSharp**](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp)

[CefSharp - Embedded Chromium for .NET](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp)

this might help you.

**Examples**

- [WinForm](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/tree/master/CefSharp.WinForms.Example)
- [WPF](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/tree/master/CefSharp.Wpf.Example)